# How to parse TextBox to arguments to run a exe

Tags: c#

I need to parse login and password from textbox to arguments to run a exe

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        string username = textBox1.Text;
        string password = textBox2.Text;

        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.FileName = "Main.exe";
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = "-IFZUpdatedOk_K0 -gna -login @username -pwd  @password";
        p.Start();
        p.WaitForExit();


     //   System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Main.exe", " -IFZUpdatedOk_K0 -gna -login email@email.com -pwd mypassword");
    }``
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. There's nothing in the code you wrote that appears to attempt to include the values of the `username` and `password` variables in your `Arguments` value. Did you mean to write `p.StartInfo.Arguments = $"-IFZUpdatedOk_K0 -gna -login {username} -pwd  {password}";`? Or if using a C# version before 6, something like `p.StartInfo.Arguments = "-IFZUpdatedOk_K0 -gna -login " + username + " -pwd " + password;`? If not that, then what are you asking?

Comment: What you want to look at is String.Format() for your arguments, the @ won't include variables in your string...

Comment: tanks everyone i remove @ and works

Comment: @Eric: `tanks everyone i remove @ and works`: Thats not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "-IFZUpdatedOk_K0 -gna -login " + username + " -pwd " + password;
```

or

```
p.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format("-IFZUpdatedOk_K0 -gna -login {0} -pwd  {1}"), usernmae, password);
```

Comment: Also `$"-IFZUpdatedOk_K0 -gna -login {username} -pwd  {password}"` works.